# Does Gray Code converted to decimal give us a fractal?

Tags: fractals, gray-code

I have noticed that Gray code converted to decimal and plotted into a chart (for instance, 2 is binary 10, but in Gray code it's 11, 11 in binary is 3 so I plotted 2 to 3, and so on) give a fractal-like curve. Here is one with all the numbers that can be presented in a 7-bit Gray code (that is, integers less than 128):
[image: Gray code converted to decimal]

So, I am interested, does that curve fit the mathematical definitions of a fractal?

Comment: It looks like you are considering a particular Gray code, the one that has some built-in self similarity.

Comment: I think what you really mean is just that it's self-similar. But if you examine the definition of the code, you'll see why: the second half is the same as the first half, but turned upside down and with a 1 on the beginning of each element.

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "fractal"?  The term does not have a universally accepted definition in mathematics, thus before you ask "is $X$ a fractal?", you need to be more specific about what you mean by the term.  (2) If it is a fractal, so what?  If you classify this as a fractal, what do you gain?  Typically, when we ask "is $X$ a $Y$?" we do so because we have tools for studying $Y$s which we might like to use in order to study $X$.  What tools used to study fractals do you want to use in order to study this code?